# Leaflet Map Rails, Tiles Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet

Using the `gem leaflet-rails`

My initializer has the `tile_layer` and `max_zoom`

there is a height to the div: `.mapid { height: 500px; }`
Here is my html.erb

```
<% @imgData.each_with_index do |data, index| %>
<%=image_tag( data['images']["standard_resolution"]['url'] )%>
<div class="mapid" >
    <%= map(:container_id => "map" + index.to_s, :center => {
      :latlng => [data['location']['latitude'], data['location']['longitude']],
      :zoom => 18
    }) %>
</div>
```

When I hover on those links for the img src, they are valid and will lead me to a tile.
[image]

My tiles get loaded properly. There are no js errors, but nothing is being displayed... Any ideas?

Comment: DId you give a height to your map container `div` with CSS?

Comment: Yes: `.mapid {
 height: 500px;
}`

Comment: You are a god send ^^^ thank you @chrki

Comment: I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a height to the `#map<nr>` containers within that outer `#mapid` container, or you can do `.leaflet-container { height:500px }`.